# Dynamically add addresses to MapQuest JavaScript Geocode Module

Tags: javascript, geocoding, mapquest

I am attempting to use the MapQuest Geocoding Module within the JavaScript API to dynamically batch geocode addresses:

```
MQA.withModule('geocoder', function() {

    var addresses = new Array();

    $.getJSON('get_marker_json.php', function( data ) {

        $.each(data, function(i, item) {
            addresses.push(street: item.address, city: item.city, state: item.state, postalCode: item.zip);
        });

    });

    /*Pass an array of locations to be geocoded and placed on map*/
    map.geocodeAndAddLocations(

        // add addresses from array here
        addresses

    );

});
```

This does not work however. It seems that the addresses must be pre-defined.  For example:

```
map.geocodeAndAddLocations([
            'Littleton CO',
            { city: 'Steamboat Springs', state: 'CO' },
            { street: '555 17th St', postalCode: '80202' },
            'Winter Park CO'
        ]);
```

How might I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getJSON()` call is asynchronous, meaning `map.geocodeAndAddLocations()` is being run while the network request is still out, and `addresses` is empty.

Move your call to `map.geocodeAndAddLocations()` into the callback in `getJSON()` after assembling the `addresses` array. (Also, why are you assembling an array of JSON strings?)

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, I corrected the code above to be an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can also make the getJSON() call synchronous by adding the following beforehand and make it wait until array is filled:

```
$.ajaxSetup({'async': false});
```